# Multiple Updates in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I want:

```
1. To be able to update multiple sites with one upload

2. News page will now database driven

3. Updates in common elements likes LOGOS, COUNTRIES, ADDRESSES, TELEPHONES, FAX NUMBER and EMAIL ADDRESSES can be done with limited HTML knowledge
```

Hello guys..Is this possible in Drupal 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

But you might need to search for right module or write your own. You might need install the features module or the domain access. But what you are asking is quite general question, with Drupal everything is possible. But you might need to write PHP code for matching your special needs.

Comment: He means search for a module that matches your needs on Drupal's [contributed module list](http://drupal.org/project/modules), or [write your own module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) to do what you want. Also check out [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush), it can automate a lot of things

Comment: Excatly Clive. And Sam your question is quite big. So the simple answer is just yes. It is possible.